# Simulate gestures in Android

Tags: android, gestures

How can I simulate gestures programmatically.

I get all the points and I would like my app to repeat these drawings.

```
public void onGestureStarted(GestureOverlayView gestureOverlayView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Started gesture: \n" + motionEvent.getRawX() + "\n" +
                    motionEvent.getRawY() + "\n" + motionEvent.getEventTime());

            gestures.add(new GesturePoint(motionEvent.getRawX(), motionEvent.getRawY(), 100));
        }

        @Override
        public void onGesture(GestureOverlayView gestureOverlayView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            gestures.add(new GesturePoint(motionEvent.getRawX(), motionEvent.getRawY(), 100));
            Log.e("TAG", "gesture: \n" + motionEvent.getRawX() + "\n" +
                    motionEvent.getRawY() + "\n" + motionEvent.getEventTime());
        }

        @Override
        public void onGestureEnded(GestureOverlayView gestureOverlayView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            gestures.add(new GesturePoint(motionEvent.getRawX(), motionEvent.getRawY(), 100));

            Log.d("TAG", "Ended gesture: \n" + motionEvent.getRawX() + "\n" +
                    motionEvent.getRawY() + "\n" + motionEvent.getEventTime());

            g.addStroke(new GestureStroke(gestures));
            gestureOverlayView.setGesture(g);
```

Is there any method like startDraw(Arraylist)?

i need it to simulate user interaction.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *MotionEvent* class. Simple use:

```
MotionEvent emulateActionDown = MotionEvent.obtain
(
    // The time (in ms) when the user originally pressed down to start a stream of position events. 
    // This must be obtained from uptimeMillis().
    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
    // The the time (in ms) when this specific event was generated. 
    // This must be obtained from uptimeMillis().
    SystemClock.uptimeMillis()+20,
    // The kind of action being performed, such as ACTION_DOWN.
    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 
    // The X coordinate of this event.
    1, 
    // The Y coordinate of this event.
    1, 
    // The state of any meta / modifier keys that were in effect when the event was generated. 
    0
)
```

Example shows a simple ACTION_DOWN emulation. Then, you can pass this event to *onTouchEvent* method of a View:

```
myView.onTouchEvent(emulateActionDown);
```

Take a look here: [MotionEvent -> obtain](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#obtain%28long,%20long,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int%29)