# How to implement voice-controlled browser in Android

Tags: android, android-service, voice-recognition, android-browser

I want to develop an Android application that run in background and do some actions  via voice control.

For example, I want to use my voice to open a website in my browser, scroll the page up/down or click a specific link .....

Now, I just can only use my voice to open an url in browser but I was stuck in simulating android touch gesture to scroll up/down or click link...

Can somebody suggest me a solution? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Gesture simulation is described here:

[Simulate gestures in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462343/simulate-gestures-in-android)

However, that will not help you since you will not have understanding where the link is located and so on. You want full controlled voice browser, not gesture simulation. You have to modify the browser itself to listen for the voice commands and perform actions.

It was once done for Nokia, see the video here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjIUv84U_E0

but as far as I understand it never went opensource

In general if you want to control any application, you still need a cooperation with that application to expose possible actions and their names. This usually implemented through Android accessibility framework, you can read about it here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your solution.
I just want to develop an voice assistant application that can run in background as a service and interact with other apps, not only browser. Is there any way to trigger voice control without editing those app? P/s:
Maybe I only need simulating swipe right/left/up/down :)

Comment: In many cases you need to cooperate with the application to know which buttons are there, what to press and so on. This can be done with https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html accessibility framework. I added the link to the answer too.